# Is this the correct behavior when dealing with lists?

Tags: java, list

If I create a list and add ten elements then copy the list object to another and call list.clear on the second list, both of the lists are cleared.

```
Random random = new Random();
List<Double> list1 = new ArrayList<Double>();
List<Double> list2 = new ArrayList<Double>();

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    list1.add(random.nextDouble());
}

list2 = list1; //Both lists have ten elements

list1.clear(); //Both lists are now empty
```

Is this normal? Am I missing something?
If I iterate through the first list and add the elements one by one this does not occur, only with the `list2 = list1` line.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I copy the contents of one ArrayList into another?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8441664/how-do-i-copy-the-contents-of-one-arraylist-into-another)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
list2 = list1; //Both lists have ten elements
```

This doesn't copy `list1` to `list2`. It makes the variable `list2` refer to the same list as `list1`. Both variables point at the same list object.

**Before**

```
list1 -----> [ArrayList #1]

list2 -----> [ArrayList #2]
```

**After**

```
list1 --+--> [ArrayList #1]
        |
list2 --+    [ArrayList #2]   (orphaned, will be garbage collected)
```

To copy the elements of the first list to the second, instead do:

```
list2.addAll(list1);
```

(If `list2` weren't empty you would also need `list2.clear()`.)

Answer (score 2):

```
list2 = list1;
```

This doesn't copy `list1` to `list2`, but makes `list2` reference (point to) list1. Since both `list1` and `list2` now point to the same list, it doesn't matter if you use `list1` or `list2` since both will be acting on the same list.

If you want to copy it, do (after adding the elements):

```
final List<Double> list2 = new ArrayList<Double>(list1);
```

This also means that `List<Double> list2 = new ArrayList<Double>()` is superfluous.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because both lists are pointing to the same value in memory. Just populate the list with a foreach loop.

Comment: Instead of a `foreach`, one should use [`addAll(Collection<? extends E> c)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#addAll-java.util.Collection-). This can be more performant.