# how to copy one arrayList to another without refrencing first?

Tags: android, arraylist, copy

I tried all way but always it is referencing the previous one.

```
mListPreviousData = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < mAddedList.size(); i++) {
    mListPreviousData.add(mAddedList.get(i));
}
```

Comment: just do mListPreviousData = (ArrayList<YourType>) mAddedList.clone(); You need to cast in to your arraylist type

Comment: type of both arrayList is same that's why it is referencing the previous one

Comment: You can use [this](https://github.com/google/guava) library or by constructor you can get **shallow** copy.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I copy the contents of one ArrayList into another?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8441664/how-do-i-copy-the-contents-of-one-arraylist-into-another)

Comment: If you do  not want to create two separate  list by cloning your list object  , Then you need to create Data List Item Each time within loop and then add into your mListPreviousData list .Meas you need to create new object each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mListPreviousData = new ArrayList<>(); 
mListPreviousData.addAll(mAddedList);
```

Comment: Please provide a specific body to your answer, for better understanding.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make a deep copy of the underlying objects:

```
mListPreviousData = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < mAddedList.size(); i++) {
    mListPreviousData.add(mAddedList.get(i).clone());
}
```

Preferably, you implement your own `clone()` method.

Edit:

Or do a deep copy of the entire arraylist:

```
mListPreviousData = (..cast to your type..) mAddedList.clone();
```

Comment: drawback if the original list data is changed the cloned copy will automatically updated

Comment: same thing i don't want i need two separate lists.

Comment: If you do not want to create two separate list by cloning your list object , Then you need to create Data List Item Each time within loop and then add into your mListPreviousData list .Meas you need to create new object each time