# Cloning a java LinkedHashMap

Tags: java, hashmap, clone

What is the best of cloning a `LinkedHasMap` in Java?

I already tried:

```
Map<String, Object> clonedMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>(originalMap);
```

But that didn't work.

Comment: Why didn't it work? What do you want it to do?

Comment: Define "didn't work". `new Map(map)` makes a "shallow" copy - the references are the same. If you mean a "deep" copy (where all keys and values are *also* cloned) the answer depends entirely on the implementation of the the key and value classes.

Comment: As Bohemian has said, deep copy is likely what you are after. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/64036/how-do-you-make-a-deep-copy-of-an-object-in-java).

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to get a deep copy is to serialize the map and then deserialize it. The faster way is to go thought the whole map, clone each key/value and put it to a new map.

In case you need a shallow copy - your snippet does that correctly.

Comment: Although serialization is a simple solution, if you want something automatic, I'd rather use reflection. But even better is to have all your cloneable classes implement the Cloneable interface (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Cloneable.html).