# Creating a copy of an object without coping it's property references

Tags: java

To explain:

```
public class SomeClass {
  int aNumber = 0;

  public void changeNumber(int number){
    aNumber = number;
  }

  public int getNumber(){
    return aNumber;
  }
} 


public class Testapp {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    NewClass object1 = new NewClass();
    NewClass object2 = object1;

    object1.changeNumber(5);
    object2.changeNumber(2);
    System.out.println("object1: "+object1.getNumber());
    System.out.println("object2: "+object2.getNumber());
  }
}
```

This will output:
object1: 2
object2: 2

How would I make it output:
object1: 5
object2: 2

Comment: See here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/64036/how-do-you-make-a-deep-copy-of-an-object-in-java

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have two options:

1) Implement a copy constructor:

```
public SomeClass(SomeClass c) {
  this.aNumber = c.aNumber;
}
```

And then to create a copy:

```
SomeClass object2 = new SomeClass(object1);
```

2) Implement the Cloneable interface and override Object.clone():

```
public class SomeClass implements Cloneable {
  public SomeClass clone() {
    super.clone();
  }
}
```

Then to create a copy:

```
SomeClass object2 = object1.clone();
```

**Note:** I have omitted any code that does not change.

Comment: `clone()` should not use a constructor to create the new object. It should call `super.clone()`.

Answer (score 1):

You are not doing a copy of the object, you are copying the reference. That means that both variables refer to the same object.

To create an object, you must use `new` or call a method that uses it.

Since you want a copy, you should make your object implement `Cloneable` (and, if needed, implement `clone()`).

Answer (score 1):

How you have it set up right now is that both `object1` and `object2` are pointing at the same spot in memory.  You will have to do this:

```
NewClass object1 = new NewClass();
NewClass object2 = new NewClass();
object1.changeNumber(5);
object2.changeNumber(2);
System.out.println("object1: "+object1.getNumber());
System.out.println("object2: "+object2.getNumber());
```

This way, `object1` and `object2` are completely separate Objects.

Comment: The simplest solution, maybe not the most detailed, but if this is good enough for the OP, it's easier than dealing with `Clonable`

Answer (score 0):

```
 public class Testapp {
public static void main(String[] args) {
 NewClass object1 = new NewClass();
 NewClass object2 = new NewClass();
  object1.changeNumber(5);
 object2.changeNumber(2);
 System.out.println("object1: "+object1.getNumber());
 System.out.println("object2: "+object2.getNumber());   } }
```

You should call a new instantiation of the object otherwise they refer to the same position in memory.

Answer (score 0):

**1.** You have **copied the reference Not the object.**

**2.** As both the **Object Reference Variables are pointing to the Same object on the heap, you are getting 2 as the answer for both of them..**

**3.** Use `new` **operator to create and assign another object to the object2 reference.**

**One more thing... its not NewClass, but SomeClass as its mentioned in your code**

```
SomeClass object1 = new SomeClass();
SomeClass object2 = new SomeClass();
object1.changeNumber(5);
object2.changeNumber(2);
System.out.println("object1: "+object1.getNumber());
System.out.println("object2: "+object2.getNumber());
```

Answer (score 0):

Object is an instance of class and capable of holding state. Object is created using `new` operator - in your case object is created at `new NewClass()`

`NewClass object1` and `NewClass object2` are object reference variable - these are like pointers in C/C++. Reference variable do not hold state - they just point to memory location where object state is located.

When you say `NewClass object1 = new NewClass()` - the `new` operator creates instance of NewClass and returns the memory location that gets stored in `object1` reference variable. When you say `NewClass object2 = object1` - the memory location details held in `object1` are copied to `object2` - important thing to note over here is that no new object is created. There is only one object and hence only one state - that is why when you change state using `object1` or `object2` reference variable the previous value is overwritten.

If you want two objects then you need to invoke `new` twice - that will allocate separate memory location for each object. In case you have an object and want similar copy of the object - copying its state to new memory location - then you need to use the `clone()` method of `Object` class. Cloning creates a new object and copies the current state of object to new object - so if you call `NewClass object2 = object1.clone()` that would create new object and copy state of object1 to that, returning the reference to `object2` - here `object2` is also called as local copy. You need to follow java specifications for cloning - that is you need to implement `Cloneable` interface to support cloning of objects - please refer this link to start with http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clone_(Java_method)