# Deep Copy an Object

Tags: java, object, copy

Is it possible to **deep copy** an `Object` out of the box? i.e. any other way than coding a `clone` function manually.

Comment: Take a look at http://code.google.com/p/cloning/

Comment: Thanks. This lib is doing the trick. but I am not looking for a lib. I'm looking for Logic. i.g. How this lib is doing this?

Comment: That's correct. But I checked the code. It contains very little comment. It is possible to _study_ the code though but someone may describe the logic much faster and better. 
btw, I will keep studying the code as the last option. Thanks.

Comment: Here is a [SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/64036/how-do-you-make-a-deep-copy-of-an-object-in-java) that suggets - serialization/deseralization.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Cloning does not *necessarily* perform a deep copy.  In fact, the default implementation of `Object.clone()` creates a *shallow* copy.
2. If the object's closure consists of objects that implement `Serializable` or `Externalizable`, you can use `ObjectOutputStream` and `ObjectInputStream` to create a deep copy ... but it is expensive.
3. The [`cloning`](http://code.google.com/p/cloning/) library is another option, but my initial reading of the code is that it relies on the class of every object in the graph providing a no-argument constructor.  Then it will then patch the resulting object to have a copy of the original object's state.  This process might have undesirable side-effects, depending on what the no-args constructor actually does.

In short, I don't think there is a *universal* solution.

Comment: There can't be really _universal_ solution, since it that would require cloning open files and network connections, running threads including waits, and stuff like that.

Comment: @hyde - yea, but even including the types where copying is theoretically impossible, there is still a set of types that could be copyable but aren't.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use java.lang.reflect.

java.lang.Class expose all fields and allows reading public fields and calling public methods.

Only the private field without accessors can't be cloned.

Answer (score 0):

I briefly looked at the `cloning` library code. It does what Serialization does that is get the graph of the object internal and instead of writing to file, it writes to a memory location = which is the clone of the object. So although its faster than Serialization, its certainly doing the same thing.

Comment: Not exactly.  Object deserialization creates the new objects using a JVM backdoor that creates an object without running its constructor.  (The default `Object.clone()` method does something similar ...)