# Deep Copy of a Generic Type in Java

Tags: java, generics, clone, generic-programming

How does deep copies (clones) of generic types `T, E` work in Java? Is it possible?

```
E oldItem;
E newItem = olditem.clone(); // does not work
```

Comment: check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/64036/how-do-you-make-a-deep-copy-of-an-object-in-java

Comment: There is no general way to clone an object in Java. Specific classes have public clone() methods, but here you don't know which class it is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is no. Cause there is no way to find out which class will replace your generic type `E` during compile time, unless you [Bind it to a type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html).

Java way of cloning is shallow, for deep cloning, we need to provide our own implementation

The work-around for it, is to create a contract like this

```
public interface DeepCloneable {
    Object deepClone();
}
```

and an implementor should be having its own **deep-clone** logic

```
class YourDeepCloneClass implements DeepCloneable {

    @Override
    public Object deepClone() {
        // logic to do deep-clone
        return new YourDeepCloneClass();
    }

}
```

and it can be called like below, where the generic type `E` is a bounded type

```
class Test<E extends DeepCloneable> {

    public void testDeepClone(E arg) {
        E e = (E) arg.deepClone();
    }
}
```

Comment: doing `return new YourDeepCloneClass();` is not going to work for subclasses

Comment: @newacct Thanks for your suggestion, but it was just an example and there I wan intending to use deep copy logic