# Preserving encapsulation of a generic in Java

Tags: java, oop, generics, clone, type-safety

Good evening.

I have a rather involved question. To practice Java, I've been re-implementing some of the data structures in the standard library. Stacks, LinkedLists, Trees, etc. I just established, through a very simple example, that the `java.util.Stack` class performs a deep copy when either the `peek()` or `pop()` methods are used. This is understandable, since the goal would be to protect the contents of the class from outside interference. So far, in my own implementation of the Stack (a naive implementation with a simple array, linked lists will come later), I have not cared for this at all:

```
public class ArrayStack<T> implements Stack<T> {
    private T[] data; // Will expand the array when stack is full.
    private int top; // serves as both top and count indicator.
    ...
    ...
   @Override
   public T pop() throws EmptyStackException {
    if(top == -1)
        throw new EmptyStackException("Stack is empty.");
    return data[top--]; // Shallow copy, dangerous!
}
```

Unfortunately, since a generic cannot be instantiated, I cannot assume a copy constructor and do stuff like `return new T(data[top--]);` I've been looking around in S.O and I've found two relevant threads which attempt to solve the problem by using some variant of `clone()`. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16436591/deep-copy-of-a-generic-type-in-java) thread suggests that the class's signature be extended to:

```
public class ArrayStack<T extends DeepCloneableClass> implements Stack<T>
...
```

where `DeepCloneableClass` is a class that implements an interface that allows for "deep cloning" (see the top response in that thread for the relevant details). The problem with this method, of course, is that I can't really expect from standard classes such as `String` or `Integer` to be extending that custom class of mine, and, of course, all my existing jUnit tests are now complaining at compile-time, since they depend on such Stacks of Integers and Strings. So I don't feel as if this solution is viable.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/803971/cloning-with-generics/1243141#1243141) thread suggests the use of a third-party library for cloning pretty much any object. While it appears that this library is still supported (latest bug fixes date from less than a month ago), I would rather not rely on third-party tools and use whatever Java can provide for me. The reason for this is that the source code for these ADTs might be someday shared with undergraduate college students, and I would rather not have them burdened with installing extra tools.

I am therefore looking for a simple and, if possible, efficient way to maintain a generic Java data structure's inner integrity while still allowing for a simple interface to methods such as `pop()`, `peek()`, `popFront()`, etc.

Thanks very much for any help!

Jason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you need to clone the objects?

Your stack just has a collection of references. You probably don't need to clone them, just make a new array and put the appropriate references in it, then throw away the old array.

Comment: The reason for which I need to clone the objects is because, if you notice from the code above, when implementing pop(), I am returning a reference to the first object in the stack. What I would ideally want is a deep copy, but, unfortunately, I can't use a copy constructor with generics! By making a new array, are you implying that I should just keep the reference to the top element which I will eventually return, and then just recreate a new array which will lack a reference to the top element? That sounds like it might work, but is horribly inefficient.

Comment: That's fine - you would want to return a reference to the first object in the stack. Collections don't make copies of the objects, since the developer may want to alter the object for everyone who has a reference. You need to keep a reference to the first object, then make a new array containing the existing references to all the other objects.

Comment: I would like to confirm what you just said, about how Collections in the Java Standard Library actually do **not** make deep copies of references. I temporarily forgot that Strings and Integers were immutable and thus a reference to them cannot really affect them. Full response of what confused me will be added to a self-answer. Thanks a million!

Comment: You definitely do not want to clone the objects being stored in the stack. A developer using your stack would expect that if she put an object on the stack, she would be able to get the exact same instance off again later, not a copy of it. And, if she chose to mutate that object in some way in the meantime, it would be the mutated one that was popped later, not a copy of the original one. You may, however, want to consider whether thread safety is important in your implementation.

Comment: @Jason: No, collections do not copy their contents. It's not really about the objects -- it's about the references. Collections store references; what objects they point to, they really don't care. In fact, there is no generic way to make a copy of an object in Java.

Answer (score 1):

`Integer`, `Strings`, etc are all immutable, so their contents are safe by design.

As for custom objects, while experienced Java Programmers will certain have mixed feelings about it, [implementing a custom interface](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1138790/664577) is certainly one way to approach the problem.

Another one is to make `<T extends Serializable>` (which is implemented by `Integer`, `String`, etc) and ["clone" through serialization](http://www.obsidianscheduler.com/blog/easy-deep-cloning-of-serializable-and-non-serializable-objects-in-java/).

But if you want to teach your students the "right way" I would definitively use a third party library... You can just create a lib folder in your project and configure you build tool / IDE to add the needed jars to the Classpath using relative paths, so your undergraduate students will not have to install or setup anything.

Just for reference, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2156120/java-recommended-solution-for-deep-cloning-copying-an-instance) may be very useful.

I've been teaching Java introductory classes (as an IT Instructor / not as a college Professor) using this kind of approach, and it is way less painful than it sounds.

Comment: Indeed, the fact that Strings and Integers are immutable led me to an example that made me believe that the standard library makes deep copies of returned values, which was a wrong assumption. I'll detail what I did wrong in a self-response. Thanks!

Comment: I'm also seeing that cloning library being used in a lot of different places. I'll look it up in more detail.

Comment: You will, plus libraries such as [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) and [Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/) will certainly enable you to write cleaner code. Please don't forget to accept Jason or my answer so that the stackoverflow community can benefit from our experience.

Answer (score 0):

The comments helped me understand what I had wrong. I was using the following example to "prove" to myself and others that the Java Standard Library's Collections do a deep copy when providing references to objects in the Collection:

```
import java.util.Stack;

public class StackTestDeepCopy {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Stack<String> st = new Stack<String>();
        st.push("Jim");
        st.push("Jill");
        String top = st.peek();
        top = "Jack";
        System.out.println(st); 
    }
}
```

When printing st, I saw that objects had been unchanged, and concluded that a deep copy had taken place. Wrong! `String`s are immutable, and therefore the statement `top = "Jack"` does not in any way modify the `String` (not that any `Object` would be "modified" by a statement like that, but I wasn't thinking straight), it just makes the reference point to a new place on the heap. A new example, involving an actually mutable class, made me understand the error in my ways.

Now that this problem has been solved, I'm quite baffled by the fact that the standard library allows for this. Why is it that accessing elements in the standard library is implemented as a shallow copy? Sounds very unsafe.

Comment: It's not a shallow copy - it's merely returning the reference you pushed onto the stack in the first place. You're just assigning a completely new object reference to "top" in the line after peek(). Shallow copying means something else.

Comment: _Why is it that accessing elements in the standard library is implemented as a shallow copy_? It isn't, it returns references to objects. When you don't need mutability, you can just design immutable objects.

Answer (score -1):

`java.util.Stack` doesn't do a deep copy:

```
import java.util.Stack;
public class Test {
    String foo;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test test = new Test();
        test.foo = "bar";
        Stack<Test> stack = new Stack<Test>();
        stack.push(test);
        Test otherTest = stack.pop();
        otherTest.foo = "wibble";
        System.out.println("Are the same object: "+(test.foo == otherTest.foo));
    }
}
```

Results in:

```
Are the same object: true
```

If it did do a copy then test and otherTest would point to a different object. A typical stack implementation simply returns a reference to the same object that was added onto the stack, not a copy.

---

You probably also want to set the array item to null before returning, otherwise the array will still hold a reference to the object.

Comment: Yeah, I figured the shallow copying situation out. And right, I'm not allowing garbage collection to kick in by not "nullifying" the reference. Thanks for the pointer, no pun intended.