# Java Graph (Structure) Deep copy

Tags: java, structure, deep-copy

Well, I have some class (Vertex), that contains HashSet in it; and at some point, I need to deep copy that element;

I wrote some code, but sometimes it doesn't work; I'm working on this bug for several days and can't fix it... If anybody has enough time to read the code and find it, I'll be very grateful. Thank you in advance.

Well, here is function:

```
public Vertex getCopy(Vertex copyFrom, Vertex copyTo, HashSet<Vertex> created){

    copyTo.setId(copyFrom.getId());
    copyTo.setColor(copyFrom.getColor());
    copyTo.setCount(copyFrom.getCount());
    copyTo.setDepth(copyFrom.getDepth());
    copyTo.setDistance(copyFrom.getDistance());
    copyTo.setHeurist(copyFrom.getHeurist());
    copyTo.setVisited(copyFrom.isVisited());
    copyTo.setPath(copyFrom.getPath());

    created.add(copyTo);

    HashSet<Vertex> copyToNeighs = new HashSet<Vertex>();
    HashSet<Vertex> copyFromNeighs = new HashSet<Vertex>();
    copyFromNeighs.addAll(copyFrom.getNeighbours());

    Iterator<Vertex> it = copyFromNeighs.iterator();

    while (it.hasNext()){
        Vertex curr = it.next();

        if (!created.contains(curr)){
            Vertex newOne = new Vertex();
            newOne = getCopy(curr, newOne, created);
            copyToNeighs.add(newOne);
        } else {
            Iterator<Vertex> itr = created.iterator();
            while (itr.hasNext()){
                Vertex tmp = itr.next();
                if (tmp.equals(curr)){
                    copyToNeighs.add(tmp);
                    break;
                }
            }

        }
    }

    copyTo.setNeighbours(copyToNeighs);

    return copyTo;
}
```

and i want this method to copy from CopyFrom to CopyTo.
here is How i call this method:

```
Vertex newOne = new Vertex();
Vertex newCurr = new Vertex();
HashSet<Vertex> seen1 = new HashSet<Vertex>();
HashSet<Vertex> seen2 = new HashSet<Vertex>();
newOne = newOne.getCopy(tmp, newOne, seen1);
newCurr = newCurr.getCopy(curr, newCurr, seen2);
```

other methods (like .getNEighbours(), .addNeighbours())work properly, I've tested them hundreds of time;

Comment: I forgot to say, that Vertex.id is always unique, so i've overrided hash function of Vertex like that:

Comment: @Override
    public int hashCode() {
   return this.id;
  }

Comment: do you want to copy single vertex or the whole graph? And, what do you mean by "doesn't work"?

Comment: I need whole graph. And what I mean, is that, in some cases the copied one isn't exact copy. Some neighbors have different value...

Comment: Did you override the `equals` method of a `Vertex`?  If so, what does it do?

Comment: @Override
 public boolean equals(Object obj) {
  if (this == obj)
   return true;
  if (obj == null)
   return false;
  if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
   return false;
  Vertex other = (Vertex) obj;
  if (id != other.id)
   return false;
  return true;
 }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`created` is the wrong concept.  You have a set of nodes in the "from" graph, and you're creating a set of *new* nodes in the "to" graph.  `created.add(copyTo)` will add a new node, from the "to" graph, to the set.  But when you go through `created.iterator` to see if a node is already there, you're looking for a node from `copyFromNeighs`, which is a node in the "from" graph.  It looks to me like this will never succeed.  Or else the result will be that you'll have nodes in the "to" graph pointing to nodes in the "from" graph.

Basically, I believe you need `created` to be a `HashMap<Vertex,Vertex>`, not a set.  The "key" of the `HashMap` would be a node in the "from" graph, and the "value" would be the corresponding node in the "to" graph.  Then, when you look at the neighbors of a "from" node, you get the corresponding "to" node (if it's already been copied) from the map, and add that to the neighbors of your newly created "to" node.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to create a deep copy is to serialize into memory and then deserialize, see this question: [How do you make a deep copy of an object in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64036/how-do-you-make-a-deep-copy-of-an-object-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

you need more consistent way to map source vertices onto resulting vertices. Declare `created` as hashmap, not hashset. Create new vertex only when  `created.get(oldVertex)==null`.