# WebSphere MQ Content Enricher in Java

Tags: java, jms, messaging, ibm-mq

How would you implement a Content Enricher in WebSphere MQ using Java?

Given an existing input message is provided from a queue, here are some of my ideas, none of which satisfies me:

1. Deep-clone the message object. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64036/how-do-you-make-a-deep-copy-of-an-object-in-java) is an explanation of how it could be done, but I can't find either
   `clone()` or `serialize()` methods for the javax.jms.Message class.
2. Take the original message, set the additional properties using `setXXXProperty()` and send it
   forward. This throws an exception suggesting that the message is
   read-only.
3. Create a new message, iterate over properties of the
   existing message and set them to the new message.
   `getPropertyNames()` can help to do this, but it says nothing about
   types of properties, so this information will be lost.

Comment: 1 - No. there is others Message types (TextMessage, ByteMessage ...). 2. Optimal. 3 No. Description and implementation from apache camel http://camel.apache.org/content-enricher.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, IBM integration bus can do it in a message flow... But let me provide a WMQ Java answer also:

The message object that is received can be modified and sent back ... All you need to do is to read all the stuff you need from that message to some java object. For example you can use a Map for Properties. Then call  clearProperties() and then set the modified properties. The issue of readonly goes away after calling clearProperties() (http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/jms/Message.html#clearProperties%28%29)

So a mix of (2) and (3) can help in solving the problem.

Comment: Message Broker for current task is overkill.

Comment: Neeraj, you were right. 
A correction to approach #2: Instead of using setXXXProperty() where XXX is the name of a type, it is recommended to use setObjectProperty(). This ensures the property preserves its type.