# How to perform correctly a deep and a shallow copy in java

Tags: java, interface, copy, deep-copy, shallow-copy

**1. Definitions**

**-** The class `Object` has a protected method `clone` which performs a shallow copy of the object, this method should be overridden in any class cloneable.

**-** There is a very particular `Cloneable` interface, when it's implemented in a class, it does not require the redefinition of the `clone` method.

**-** The declaration: `class X implements Cloneable` 
mentioned that class X can make a deep copy by calling the `clone` method which is the `clone` method of `Object` class or method provided by X.

**1.1** I want to know if the definitions and rules described above are correct or not?

**2. Example**

When i want to make a deep copy of an object of a class, i used the following example:

```
class A implements Cloneable
{
    int valueA = 10;
    B b = new B();

    public A clone()
    {
        A result = new A();
        try
        {
            result = (A)(super.clone());
        }
        catch (CloneNotSupportedException e)
        {
        }
        return result;
    }
}

class B
{
    int valueB = 20;
}

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        A a = new A();
        A a1 = a.clone();

        a1.valueA = 12;
        a1.b.valueB = 64;

        System.out.println("a.valueA = " + a.valueA);
        System.out.println("a1.valueA = " + a1.valueA);

        System.out.println("a.b.valueB = " + a.b.valueB);
        System.out.println("a1.b.valueB = " + a1.b.valueB);
    }
}
```

The output is :

a.valueA = 10

a1.valueA = 12

a.b.valueB = 64

a1.b.valueB = 64

I see that the deep copy is not well done because the `valueB` of object field `b` in object `a` is modified.

**2.1** Why i get this ? is it due to my lack of comprehension of how should i make deep copy ? or the example is not enough ?

**2.2** Can anyone give two correct examples of how should i make correctly shallow and deep copy ?

Comment: Have you checked this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/184710/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deep-copy-and-a-shallow-copy   and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/64036/how-do-you-make-a-deep-copy-of-an-object-in-java

Comment: I know the difference between the two concept of shallow and deep copy, but in java the method clone and the interface Cloneable should be used to make a deep or shallow copy much easier and not copy manually all the values to the other object especially if the copied object contains other objects members ?

Comment: overriding clone method will not do deep copy automaticaly. you have to clone all the properties of Object A to cloned Object .

Comment: Thanks that helped me a lot to solve my problem. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make a deep copy, then you need to also clone B when you clone A (or create another B instance using, for example, a copy constructor). `Object.clone()` simply creates a  new instance of the objects containing references to the same objects as the object being cloned. It's a shallow copy. There is no way to correctly make a generic deep copy, simply because it often doesn't make sense:

- cloning a String, for example, is useless since Strings are immutable
- cloning a Socket, for example, makes no sense as a Socket is not clonable, since it represents an active side of a TCP connection, that can't be duplicated.

You should generally avoid using Cloneable. Prefer copy constructors instead. And favor immutability rather than deep copies.