# Get two different class instances and compare them (Java)

Tags: java, reflection

I am receiving input from my Ext JS application on the front end and I want to compare two records on the java side, the record prior to a form update on the UI side and the record after setting all the new values. I have made two references to the same type of object, one before setting new values (`oldRecord`) and one after (`newRecord`) and compare these but when I try to use `oldRecord.getClass()` on the old record it will show the new field values. Is there any way to have access to the old values? I also tried making two field arrays and passing those into my method.

```
private static Map<String, List<String>> changes;

public static <T> Map<String, List<String>> getChanges (T oldRecord, T newRecord) {

    changes = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

    try {
        if(oldRecord instanceof UserInfo && oldRecord.getClass().equals(newRecord.getClass())) {
            Field field = oldRecord.getClass().getDeclaredField("name");
            field.setAccessible(true);
            System.out.println(field.get(oldRecord));
            field = newRecord.getClass().getDeclaredField("name");
            field.setAccessible(true);
            System.out.println(field.get(newRecord));

            // will loop through all fields in both records and compare

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Exception");
    }

    return changes;
}
```

Comment: This post is useful?
http://www.sidesofmarch.com/index.php/archive/2007/08/03/use-reflection-to-compare-the-properties-of-two-objects/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are using the same object. This is the case if you have done something like this:

```
Object oldRecord = new Object();
Object newRecord = oldRecord;
newRecord.doSomethingThatModifyIt();
getChanges(oldRecord, newRecord);
```

If you have done something like this, then keep in mind that `Object newRecord = oldRecord;` does not create any new object, but just sets the 2 variables to point to the same object.

You should instead create a new object based on the old one, with some method like `clone()` that you would have to implement. Or just by manually setting the fields of the newly created object.

*Note: I have used* `Object` *but it could be any type of course.*

Comment: In my model I get the object in question, set `Object oldRecord = original;` then set the new fields, then do `Object newRecord = original;` and pass these two references in.

Comment: So it is only one reference actually, since you don't create any new object. You have to use `new` somewhere to create another object. And then you'll be able to modify it independently.

Answer (score 1):

If oldRecord and newRecord reference the same object like

```
T oldRecord = new T();
T newRecord = oldRecord;
```

they will "hold" the same instance variable values as well.

To save in oldRecord the old values you must do a deep copy of the object, that means create a new object and copy the instance variable values.

SEarch for `deep copy` or cloning, maybe start here: [How do you make a deep copy of an object in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64036/how-do-you-make-a-deep-copy-of-an-object-in-java)