# Copying ArrayList<Customer> content to another ArrayList<Customer>

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have Customer class which holds 5 fields.
And I have 10 unique instance of Customer class in ArrayList<Customer> firstlist.
I copied firstlist content to new ArrayList<Customer> secondlist list with method:

```
public void copy( ArrayList<Customer> a,  ArrayList<Customer> b){
 for (int i=0;i<a.size();i++){ b.add(a.get(0)); } }
```

Problem is if I change secondlist instances, it also changes firslist instances because of reference..

How can I copy firstlist instances to secondlist so that when I change secondlist instance it doesn't effect to firtlist instance(copy of itself). Is there any method which can do that?

Comment: What about `Copy Constructor` of Customer class? Create a new instance of Customer. some thing like that `public Customer(Customer c){...}`

Comment: Change it to `b.add(new Customer(a.get(0));`

Comment: You have to make a [deep copy of your list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/64036/how-do-you-make-a-deep-copy-of-an-object-in-java)

Comment: @Braj you're assuming `Customer` class has such constructor, but this isn't stated anywhere in the question.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I am giving some suggestion.

Comment: @Braj me too, by voting this question to close as duplicate.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Your solution is perfect but the question is about object references in `ArrayList`. Somewhat similar to it.

Comment: @Braj create a deep clone of each `Customer` in the `List` and pass each clone to the new `List`. I don't see any complication on that.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I think now the OP has enough solutions to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you need to clone the `Customer` instances.

Check the `Cloneable` interface:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Cloneable.html

and implement it in `Customer`, then in your loop add clones to
the second list, not the originals: `b.add(a.get(i).clone());`.

Comment: Check the possible duplicate Q/A to see why this is not a good option.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you add a [clone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clone_%28Java_method%29) to your `Customer` class by implementing [Cloneable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Cloneable.html).

```
public void copy( ArrayList<Customer> a,  ArrayList<Customer> b){
  for (int i=0;i<a.size();i++){ 
    b.add(a.get(i).clone()); // get(i) I think. 
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need some method of performing a deep copy of a `Customer` instance. There are several ways of doing this: implementing `clone()`, creating a copy constructor, or writing your own `deepCopy()` method or something like that that returns a deep copy of the object it's called on. Which one you use is up to you.

Copy constructors are constructors which take an instance of the same object as the argument. Generally copy constructors would just deep copy all fields from the passed object to the newly constructed one, and so are pretty easy to implement.

`deepCopy()` or other such methods would be implemented in a similar way.

I've heard varying things about Java's `clone()` method and I usually lean towards other methods of performing a deep copy, but that you can implement by implementing the `Cloneable` interface and properly implementing the `clone()` method