# Deep copying using clone method

Tags: java

Hello guys i am trying to deep copy class A. Im having trouble deep copying class A. subscriptions is an array reference that holds the objects of SubscriptionYear. Could someone help me out using the clone method to do a deep copy.

```
public class A {

private String countryNames;
private SubscriptionYear[] subscriptions;
private int size;
private int location;

public A(String country)
{
    this.countryNames = country;
}
public A(String country, int arraylength)
{
    this.countryNames = country;
    this.size = arraylength;
    subscriptions = new SubscriptionYear[size];
    location = 0;
}
//adds the subscription.
public void addSubscriptionYear(int year, double subscription)
{
        subscriptions[location]= new SubscriptionYear(year, subscription);
        ++location;
}
```

SubscriptionYear:

```
public class SubscriptionYear {

private int year;
private double subscriptions;

public SubscriptionYear(int year,double subscriptions)
{
    setYear(year);
    setSubscription(subscriptions);
}
public void setYear(int Year)
{
    this.year= Year;
}
public void setSubscription(double value)
{
    this.subscriptions = value;
}
public int getYear()
{
    return year;
}
public double getSubscription()
{
    return subscriptions;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you make a deep copy of an object in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/64036/how-do-you-make-a-deep-copy-of-an-object-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i solved my problem. this solution addressed my issue:

```
public Object clone() {
A newA = new A(this.countryNamse, this.arraylength);

for(int i=0;i<this.newA.subscriptions.length;i++) {
   newA.subscriptions[i] = subscriptions[i[]; 
 }
return newA;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public Object clone() {
    A newA = new A(countryNames);
    newA.size = size;
    newA.subscriptions = new SubscriptionYear[size];
    for(SubscriptionYear subYear : subscriptions) {
        newA.addSubscriptionYear(subYear.getYear(), subYear.getSubscription());
    }
    return newA;
}
```

Comment: i added SubscriptionYear class

Comment: If you want to perform a deep copy, SubscriptionYear will need to expose getters so that we can read the values stored inside it, or a clone method so that we can deep clone it.

Comment: sorry forgot to add the setters and getters. i modified the code