# Deep Cloning of Collections in java

Tags: java, cloning

Recently I faced this question in an Interview:

Write a function to return a deep clone instance of class Drawing

```
public class Drawing{

  public List<Shape> shapes=new LinkedList<Shape>();

}
```

where shape is an abstract class having many concrete implementations

```
public abstract class Shape implements Serializable{

}
```

Can anyone please tell how to approach this?Do we need to add the clone method in all the concrete implementations?

Comment: The fact that Shape implements Serializable is a hint. The interviewer probably simply expected you to serialize the List<Shape> and deserialize it, and to create a new Drawing instance referencing the deserialized list.

Comment: @JBNizet on the other hand if Shape has transient fields, they will be lost during serialization, but won't be lost if objects are cloned.

Comment: check if this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/64036/how-do-you-make-a-deep-copy-of-an-object-in-java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need to do is first serialize the `List<Shape>` and then deserialize and return a new instance of `Drawing` with the deserialized `List`

```
public static Drawing deepClone(Drawing drawing) {
    try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
        oos.writeObject(drawing.shapes); //Serializes the drawing.shapes

        ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(bais); 
        return new Drawing((LinkedList<Shape>)ois.readObject()); //Deserializing and reading 
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return null;
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Assuming you have a constructor in Drawing which takes in a `LinkedList<Shape>` as parameter

**EDIT**

You won't need to add `clone()` in Shape class as you override `clone()` method when you implement the `Cloneable` interface, but according to the question, they want you to create clones using `Serializable` interface.

Comment: This is a good answer, however I think it should say something about `transient` fields of `Shape` subclasses, if any. In this case, the deep cloning would not apply to these fields. I mean, as this in an interview question, maybe the OP should mention this and make it clear that it's the trade-off to pay.

Answer (score 0):

Each sub class of `Shape` knows how to create a deep copy of itself, because that is one thing `Serializable` implementations should do.  So iterate the list in `Drawing` and serialize/deserialize the `Shape` object to create your deep copy of each `Shape` in the list.

Comment: Why iterate over the list and serialize `Shape`s one by one? `LinkedList` is also `Serializable`, so serializing and deserializing the list is enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can also [use a library](http://code.google.com/p/cloning/) that is faster than serialization methods.

```
Cloner cloner=new Cloner();

MyClass clone=cloner.deepClone(o);
// clone is a deep-clone of o
```

Comment: I think he needs to know how to do it using Serializable rather than using a library as it is an interview question and he can't directly say a Library in the interview.

Comment: Why not? I think it's clever to suggest using a Library. The OP only needs to trully understand the reason why he would choose it (i.e. how serialization methods works)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using SerializationUtils.clone from Apach Commons Lang

This method is for deep cloning :

```
SomeObject cloned = org.apache.commons.lang.SerializationUtils.clone(someObject);
```

This is a simple way to clone objects but not if you look for performance.

[See documentation](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/SerializationUtils.html#clone(java.io.Serializable))

Comment: This is not an answer... Please explain why you suggest that, the benefits and the downsides of using it. Perhaps even show some example code

Comment: just edited my answer