# Is it possible to resume a continuation in Rhino multiple times?

Tags: java, rhino, continuations

I want to be able to capture a continuation and resume it several times, such that each such invocation would be independent of the others.

For example, in the following code, I'd want the 2 calls to `context.resumeContinuation` in the `run` method to result in the output: `1 1`, rather than the current output of `1 2`.

As far as I understand, the reason for the resulting output is that I always use the same `scope` object, which is being modified by the first continuation before being passed to the second one. So it seems that I should resume each continuation with a ***copy*** of the original `scope`, but type `Scriptable` has no `clone` method (or anything equivalent), and copying it using serialization/deserialization doesn't help either.

**P.S.** I am using Rhino version 1.7R5.

**Example.java**:

```
import org.mozilla.javascript.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class Example {
    public void run() throws IOException {
        Context context = Context.enter();
        context.setOptimizationLevel(-2);   // Use interpreter mode.
        Scriptable scope = context.initStandardObjects();
        scope.put("javaProxy", scope, Context.javaToJS(this, scope));

        Object capturedContinuation = null;
        try {
            String scriptSource =
                new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("example.js")));

            String scriptName = "example";
            int startLine = 1;
            Object securityDomain = null;
            Script script =
                context.compileString(scriptSource, scriptName, startLine, securityDomain);
            context.executeScriptWithContinuations(script, scope);
        } catch (ContinuationPending continuationPending) {
            capturedContinuation = continuationPending.getContinuation();
        }

        Object result = "";

        context.resumeContinuation(capturedContinuation, scope, result);
        context.resumeContinuation(capturedContinuation, scope, result);

        Context.exit();
    }

    public void captureContinuation() {
        Context context = Context.enter();
        ContinuationPending continuationPending =
            context.captureContinuation();
        Context.exit();
        throw continuationPending;
    }

    public void print(int i) {
        System.out.print(i + " ");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        new Example().run();
    }
}
```

**example.js**:

```
var i = 1;
javaProxy.captureContinuation();
javaProxy.print(i);
i = i + 1;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I came up with a working solution:

Instead of copying the `scope` object, I should've copied the `capturedContinuation` object, so the 2 calls to `resumeContinuation` would be:

```
context.resumeContinuation(deepCopy(capturedContinuation), scope, result);
context.resumeContinuation(deepCopy(capturedContinuation), scope, result);
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64036/how-do-you-make-a-deep-copy-of-an-object-in-java) offers possible imeplementations of the `deepCopy` method.

A word of caution, though: instances of Rhino's [`NativeContinuation`](https://mozilla.github.io/rhino/javadoc/org/mozilla/javascript/NativeContinuation.html) type (which is the dynamic type of `capturedContinuation` in the code above) seem to be quite large (~15KB and up when serialized to a byte array), so time/memory consumption implications should be considered when deep copying them in an application.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess but I think this might work (Rhino 1.7.6):

```java
    NativeContinuation capturedContinuation = ...
    final Object stackFrame = capturedContinuation.getImplementation();

    // Invoke once...
    context.resumeContinuation(capturedContinuation, scope, result);

    // Put stack back where it was
    capturedContinuation.initImplementation(stackFrame);

    // Invoke twice...
    context.resumeContinuation(capturedContinuation, scope, result);
```