# How to create two constructor of same class and act on value pass in second time

Tags: java, hashset

here is my attempt

```
public class blah {

HashSet<something> blah;    

public Blah() {
    this.blah = new HashSet<something>(); //this is empty constructor of something

}
```

// I want to copy all the element of Public blah in new Blah

```
public Blah(Blah initialBlah) {
    initialBlah = new Blah();
            // MAKE DEEP COPIES HERE 
            for (something c : blah){
                initialBlah.add(c);
            }

        }
```

I tried that but is not right HashSet newBlah = new HashSet();

Comment: tried to read the [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/64036/how-do-you-make-a-deep-copy-of-an-object-in-java)? you will need that to copy the `HashSet` contents as.. so far, you're just copying the references..

Comment: How do I copy a content of initial hashset in a new hashset that is not same as first hashset in the memory

Answer (score 0):

You are just copying the references. You need to copy the content fully to create a new Blah object. To achieve this, do this instead of your for loop

```
this.blah = new HashSet<something>(initblah.blah);
```

Comment: thanks, I have another question regarding hashsets.
if we have
Class A(String A, String B, int C)
now I have a new Class makes a empty hashset of A
Class D(){
HashSet<A> d = new HashSet<A>();
}
then 
Class D(D initD){
this constructor is my problem
}