# Item being added to my arrayList in ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, arraylist, android-arrayadapter

I have a list userSubs (which I access with `dm.theUser.getAllSubmissions`) of items called Submission and a draft submission I call tempSub that is not in that list. I have a list view where I want to display all the items in userSubs and the tempSub.

I create a temporary ArrayList called toDisplay and add all of the items in userSubs and then append tempSub. I then pass toDisplay into my arrayAdapter. That works fine. But when I press back and the page reloads, my tempSub has somehow been added to userSubs...  a thorough search of my own and an "find in path" search reveals that I never call the userSubs.add() function.

```
ArrayList<Submission> toDisplay = new ArrayList<>();
toDisplay = dm.theUser.getAllSubmissions();
if(dm.tempSub.draftCreated) {
    toDisplay.add(dm.tempSub);
}
saa = new submissionArrayAdapter(userSubmissions.this, toDisplay.toArray(
            new Submission[toDisplay.size()]));
```

Here is some of the array adapter code.

```
private final Activity context;
private Submission[] submissions;
//constructor
public submissionArrayAdapter(Activity context, Submission[] submissions) {

    super(context, R.layout.user_submission_row, submissions);
    this.context = context;
    this.submissions = submissions;

}
```

Any ideas on how tempSub is being added to userSubs?

Comment: Try change `toDisplay = dm.theUser.getAllSubmissions();` to `toDisplay.addAll(dm.theUser.getAllSubmissions());` Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a list userSubs (which I access with
>   dm.theUser.getAllSubmissions) of items called Submission and a draft
>   submission I call tempSub that is not in that list.

Here I assume that what you meant is:

```
userSubs = dm.theUser.getAllSubmissions);
```

> I create a temporary arraylist called toDisplay and add all of the
>   items in userSubs and then append tempSub.

I assume you're pointing to this:

```
ArrayList<Submission> toDisplay = new ArrayList<>();
toDisplay = dm.theUser.getAllSubmissions();
if(dm.tempSub.draftCreated) {
    toDisplay.add(dm.tempSub);
}
```

The problem with your code is, you're creating new variable `toDisplay` with

```
ArrayList<Submission> toDisplay = new ArrayList<>();
```

but then you're replacing the the newly created instance with:

```
toDisplay = dm.theUser.getAllSubmissions();
```

So, your `toDisplay` is not a new instance of ArrayList anymore. It's because your `toDisplay` is now referring to the instance returning by `dm.theUser.getAllSubmissions();`

When you use the following code:

```
toDisplay = dm.theUser.getAllSubmissions();
if(dm.tempSub.draftCreated) {
    toDisplay.add(dm.tempSub);
}
```

you're adding the item to the instance referred by `dm.theUser.getAllSubmissions()`.

**Please be noted**, In Java, object is passed by reference in a method and method is returning a reference of object.

What you really need is copying the list from `dm.theUser.getAllSubmissions();` to the `toDisplay`. You can use a shallow copy with something like this:

```
List<Submission> oldSubmissions = dm.theUser.getAllSubmissions();
ArrayList<Submission> toDisplay = new ArrayList<>(oldSubmissions);
```

For deep copy, please read [How do you make a deep copy of an object in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64036/how-do-you-make-a-deep-copy-of-an-object-in-java)