# How to implement heap and clone methods for a Heap class in Java

Tags: java

I am writing a class to implement a heap with both clone and equal methods. I've created specific test cases for each method.

Expected:

```
heap1: 6
heap2: 6
equals? true
heap1: 5
heap2: 6
equals? false
```

Actual:

```
heap1: 6
heap2: 6
equals? true
heap1: 5
heap2: 5
equals? true
```

My attempt

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
      String[] strings = {"red", "green", "purple", "orange", "yellow", "cyan"};
      try{
          Heap<String> heap1 = new Heap<>(strings);  
          Heap<String> heap2 = (Heap<String>)(heap1.clone());
          
          System.out.println("heap1: " + heap1.getSize());
          System.out.println("heap2: " + heap2.getSize());
          System.out.println("equals? " + heap1.equals(heap2));
          
          heap1.remove();
          
          System.out.println("heap1: " + heap1.getSize());
          System.out.println("heap2: " + heap2.getSize());
          
          System.out.println("equals? " + heap1.equals(heap2));
          }
          catch (Exception e){
              System.out.print(e.getMessage());
          }
      }
    
    
    static class Heap<E> implements Cloneable {
      private java.util.ArrayList<E> list = new java.util.ArrayList<>();
      private java.util.Comparator<? super E> c;
  
      /** Create a default heap using a natural order for comparison */
      public Heap() {
        this.c = (e1, e2) -> ((Comparable<E>)e1).compareTo(e2);
      }
  
      /** Create a heap with a specified comparator */
      public Heap(java.util.Comparator<E> c) {
        this.c = c;
      }
  
      /** Create a heap from an array of objects */
      public Heap(E[] objects) {
        this.c = (e1, e2) -> ((Comparable<E>)e1).compareTo(e2);
        for (int i = 0; i < objects.length; i++)
          add(objects[i]);
      }
  
      /** Add a new object into the heap */
      public void add(E newObject) {
        list.add(newObject); // Append to the heap
        int currentIndex = list.size() - 1; // The index of the last node
  
        while (currentIndex > 0) {
          int parentIndex = (currentIndex - 1) / 2;
          // Swap if the current object is greater than its parent
          if (c.compare(list.get(currentIndex),
              list.get(parentIndex)) > 0) {
            E temp = list.get(currentIndex);
            list.set(currentIndex, list.get(parentIndex));
            list.set(parentIndex, temp);
          }
          else
            break; // the tree is a heap now
  
          currentIndex = parentIndex;
        }
      }
  
      /** Remove the root from the heap */
      public E remove() {
        if (list.size() == 0) return null;
  
        E removedObject = list.get(0);
        list.set(0, list.get(list.size() - 1));
        list.remove(list.size() - 1);
  
        int currentIndex = 0;
        while (currentIndex < list.size()) {
          int leftChildIndex = 2 * currentIndex + 1;
          int rightChildIndex = 2 * currentIndex + 2;
  
          // Find the maximum between two children
          if (leftChildIndex >= list.size()) break; // The tree is a heap
          int maxIndex = leftChildIndex;
          if (rightChildIndex < list.size()) {
            if (c.compare(list.get(maxIndex),
                list.get(rightChildIndex)) < 0) {
              maxIndex = rightChildIndex;
            }
          }
  
          // Swap if the current node is less than the maximum
          if (c.compare(list.get(currentIndex), 
                list.get(maxIndex)) < 0) {
            E temp = list.get(maxIndex);
            list.set(maxIndex, list.get(currentIndex));
            list.set(currentIndex, temp);
            currentIndex = maxIndex;
          }
          else
            break; // The tree is a heap
        }
  
        return removedObject;
      }
  
      /** Get the number of nodes in the tree */
      public int getSize() {
        return list.size();
      }
  
      /** Return true if heap is empty */
      public boolean isEmpty() {
        return list.size() == 0;
      }
    
  // BEGIN REVEL SUBMISSION
      @Override /** Override the proctected clone method defined in
      the Object class, and stregthen its accessibility */
      public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
          return super.clone();
      }
  
      @Override /** Override the equals method in the Object cl */
      public boolean equals(Object other) {
          if (list.size() != ((Heap<E>) (other)).getSize())
              return false;
  
          for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
              if (list.get(i) != ((Heap<E>) (other)).list.get(i))
                  return false;
          }
          return true;
      }
  // END REVEL SUBMISSION
    }
```

How do I specifically return a heap from this method?

```
@Override /** Override the protected clone method defined in
        the Object class, and strengthen its accessibility */
        public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
            return list.clone();
        }
```

The issue might be coming from

```
heap1.remove();
```

Comment: You are cloning the list instead of the heap. Also, if you defined the element type as `E extends Comparable<E>` instead of just `E` you wouldn't have to have the casts to comparable.

Comment: You might consider a "copy constructor" instead of implementing `clone()`. Regardless, the problem is you directly return `list.clone()` when `Heap#clone()` should be returning a `Heap` instance.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `heap1` and `heap2` have the same internal list. `super.clone` only clones the specified object, but doesn't clone it's attributes.

Solution:

```
Heap<E> heap = new Heap();
heap.list = new ArrayList(list);
return heap;
```

As mentioned by @Slaw, you might also want to create a [copy constructor](https://www.baeldung.com/java-copy-constructor).

The process of completely cloning an object - with all the attributes and their attributes - is called a [deep clone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64036/how-do-you-make-a-deep-copy-of-an-object).

Comment: As addition: Apache Commons Lang lib has a class SerializationUtils on which you can call static method clone(). It will create a deep copy of an object. Effect is same as copy constructor. But target object must implement serializable interface. https://www.baeldung.com/java-deep-copy#1-apache-commons-lang