# Take a java object and store a copy somewhere else

Tags: java, object

I wanted to have a function that returns a copy of the object it receives, to use it somewhere else.
This is what I wrote:

```
public static PObject Instantiate(PObject obj)
{
    PObject other = obj;
    objects.add(other);
    return other;
}
```

But when I print obj + " " + other, it outputs:

```
PObjects.Wall@5315b42e
PObjects.Wall@5315b42e
```

How can I return the same object stored in a different variable?

Comment: You could create a copy constructor and then do `PObject other = new PObject(obj);`.

Comment: That'd be explicitly *not* the same object; searching for "copy Java object" will get you most of the way there. `equals` (and `hash`) exist to allow code to determine if object instances are `equal` based on whatever criteria you choose.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you make a deep copy of an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64036/how-do-you-make-a-deep-copy-of-an-object)

Answer (score 0):

You might need to implement `Cloneable` interface if you want just  shallow copy so do it like this:

```java
class PObject implements Cloneable 
{
....
 @Override
    protected Object clone()
        throws CloneNotSupportedException
    {
        return super.clone();
    }
}
```

And then use it like this:

```java
public static PObject Instantiate(PObject obj)
{
    PObject other = (PObject)obj.clone();
    objects.add(other);
    return other;
}
```

I hope this could be a benefit.