# Tell Jackson to ignore a property that is a array/collection of a specific type

Tags: java, jackson, deep-copy

### Background

- I want to clone DTOs that store values from a request in Spring Boot.

  - Sometimes it has a non-serializable field (i.e. `MultipartFile`), so I can't use the strategy to use `ObjectOutputStream`/`ObjectInputStream` like https://stackoverflow.com/a/64066/3902663 .
- I don't have control over these DTOs, so I can't add a `transient` modifier to ignore these fields.

### What I tried

I tried to write a method with Jackson's `ObjectMapper`. You can use `@JsonIgnoreType` and `ObjectMapper#addMixIn()` to ignore non-serializable fields according to their class without changing the definition of DTOs.

```java
private Object makeClone(Object obj) {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.addMixIn(MultipartFile.class, JacksonMixInForIgnoreType.class);
    try {
        return mapper.readValue(mapper.writeValueAsString(obj), obj.getClass());
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

@JsonIgnoreType
class JacksonMixInForIgnoreType {}
```

### Problem

You can't ignore the field like `MultipartFile[] fileArray;` with this strategy. When you have an array of `MultipartFile` in a DTO to upload multiple files, the code above throws an exception like this:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class java.io.FileDescriptor and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: com.example.uploadingfiles.DeepCopyDto["fileArray"]->org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile[0]->org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile["inputStream"]->java.io.FileInputStream["fd"])
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException.from(InvalidDefinitionException.java:77) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.1.jar:2.13.1]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.reportBadDefinition(SerializerProvider.java:1300) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.1.jar:2.13.1]
 ...
```

### Question

Is there any way to tell Jackson to ignore a property that is an array/collection of a specific type?

Comment: Have you tried: `.addMixIn(MultipartFile[].class, JacksonMixInForIgnoreType.class)`? It should work in the same way. Which version of Jackson do you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using Jackson Databind 2.13.1. The following code works for `MultipartFile[]` (based on @Michał Ziober's comment):

```java
private Object makeClone(Object obj) {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.addMixIn(MultipartFile.class, JacksonMixInForIgnoreType.class);
    mapper.addMixIn(MultipartFile[].class, JacksonMixInForIgnoreType.class);
    try {
        return mapper.readValue(mapper.writeValueAsString(obj), obj.getClass());
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

And I couldn't find the way to ignore `List<MultipartFile>` with `ObjectMapper#addMixIn()`.

Comment: I never tried but you could try something like `TypeReference<List<MultipartFile>> typeRef = new TypeReference<List<MultipartFile()>{};mapper.addMixIn(typeRef.getClass(),JacksonMixInForIgnoreType.class);`

Comment: `TypeReference<List<MultipartFile>> typeRef = new TypeReference<List<MultipartFile>>(){}; mapper.addMixIn(typeRef.getClass(), JacksonMixInForIgnoreType.class);` doesn't work for me. `typeRef.getClass().toString()` is `class com.example.uploadingfiles.FileUploadController$1`, not `java.util.List<org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile>`. `mapper.addMixIn(typeRef.getType().getClass(), JacksonMixInForIgnoreType.class);` is also doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
TypeFactory typeFactory = mapper.getTypeFactory();
CollectionType collectionType = typeFactory.constructCollectionType(List.class, MultipartFile.class);
mapper.configOverride(collectionType.getRawClass()).setIsIgnoredType(true);
```

this code worked for me, please try.

Comment: Thank you for your information, but this code ignores not only `List<MultipartFile>` but also other List like `List<String>`, so is not suitable for my purpose.