# Java using clone constructor with generic field

Tags: clone

Josh Bloch wrote in the Effective Java:

> Many consider clone and Cloneable broken in Java, largely because the
> rules for overriding clone are tricky and difficult to get right

and he recommends use clone constructor.

Sonar has rule ["clone" should not be overridden](https://github.com/joansmith/sonar-java/blob/master/java-checks/src/main/resources/org/sonar/l10n/java/rules/squid/S2975.html) forbidding use clone method. And Sonar recommends use clone constructor too.

I tried to use clone constructor and I got a some problem.

I have class with generics:

```
public class ClassA<T extends InterfaceB>
{
   private T fieldB;
}
```

I have 3 implementation of InterfaceB: ClassB1, ClassB2, ClassB3.
And I would like implement deep clone constructor for the ClassA.

I tried to do so:

```
//...
public ClassA(ClassA object)
{
    if (object.fieldB instanceof ClassB1 objectB1)
    {
        this.fieldB = new ClassB1(objectB1);
    }
    if (object.fieldB instanceof ClassB2 objectB2)
    {
        this.fieldB = new ClassB2(objectB2);
    }
    if (object.fieldB instanceof ClassB3 objectB3)
    {
        this.fieldB = new ClassB3(objectB3);
    }
}
//...
```

I think this code is awful:

- If somebody add new implementation ClassB4 he should add new if block in this constructor. I think with 100% chance they will forget to do. This will result in a clone error.
- This code is hard to read

When I using the classic method "clone" I don't have this problem. I call object.field.clone() and it works.

I have a question: What is the best way to deep clone by constructor if case uses generic fields

Comment: Unless I'm missing something I don't think the complexity has anything to do with the class being generic; rather, it's due to the fact that `fieldB` can be one of multiple subclasses, and you want to clone it as well as the outer object (a deep clone).  You'd have the same issue if it were non-generic, and `fieldB` were of type `InterfaceB`.

Comment: I'd look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64036/how-do-you-make-a-deep-copy-of-an-object for ideas.

Comment: @M.Justin yes, generics is a special case for example

Answer (score 0):

For this specific case you could add a `copy` method to `InterfaceB` and call that.  By being a method on the interface, it forces all implementations to implement it, so it can't be missed.

```java
public interface InterfaceB<T extends InterfaceB<T>> {
    T copy();
}
```

```java
public class ClassB1 implements InterfaceB<ClassB1> {
    @Override
    public ClassB1 copy() {
        return new ClassB1(); // TODO: Create a copy here
    }
}
```

```java
public class ClassA<T extends InterfaceB<T>>
{
   private T fieldB;

   public ClassA(ClassA<T> object) {
      this.fieldB = object.fieldB.copy();
   }
}
```